# Find documents in Mongo with TypeOrm using an array of id's as input

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to query a some documents in a MongoDB using TypeOrm (NestJs app)

Here is what I have so far:

```
function (ids: string[]): Promise<User[]> {
   return this.repository.find({
        where: {
          myId: ArrayContains(ids)
        }
   })
```

}

In my entity file, `myId` is defined as

```
  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  public myId!: string;
```

However, my code doesn't return much. The only thing I can think of is to perform the `find` for every id, like this

```
Promise.all(
    ids.map(id =>
        this.repository.findOne({
            where: { myId: id }
        })
    )
)
```

But I think there should be a way to perform this in jus one query
Any suggestions ?

Comment: so is it oid or myId ?

Comment: good point, I fixed the typo!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import { In } from 'typeorm'

function getUsers(ids: string[]): Promise<User[]> {
   return this.repository.find({
        where: {
          myId: In(ids)
        }
   })
}

...

const users: User[] = await getUsers(["1","2"]);
```

Comment: If I use `In` it returns an empty array

Comment: I figured it out. `In` is indeed the correct operator, but not for Mongo. It is all described in [this](https://typeorm.io/mongodb#using-mongoentitymanager-and-mongorepository) doc. In my case I had to replace `Repository` with `MongoRepository`